# Modulation GMSK with I/Q

Tags: digital-communications

I have a doubt about something. GMSK Modulated signal is equal to I+Q (with I = cos and Q = sin) or I+i.*Q ?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, FSK-type modulations do not use quadrature. My answer below is about quadrature, not about a specific modulation.

There are two ways to look at quadrature (I and Q) modulation: baseband, and bandpass.

In baseband, the signal is complex. You have two independent signals, each modulated using PAM, $s_I(t)$ and $s_Q(t)$. The quadrature signal is $$s_{BB}(t)=s_I(t)+js_Q(t).$$ Naturally, this signal can't physically exist. To transmit it, you need to upconvert $s_{BB}(t)$ to some carrier frequency $f_c(t)$. It becomes a bandpass signal: $$\begin{align} s(t)&=\Re(s_{BB}(t)e^{j2\pi f_ct})\\ &=s_I(t)\cos(2\pi f_ct)-s_Q(t)\sin(2\pi f_ct). \end{align}$$

Both signals carry the same information and are equivalent in many ways. $s_{BB}(t)$ is useful to simulate and analyze the system, because it does not have a carrier frequency. $s(t)$ is the signal that is actually, physically transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but IQ modulation is typically modeled using a complex signal model. In that model, the I (in-phase) component is taken to be the real part of the signal and the Q (quadrature) component is the imaginary part. So, the signal would be written something like:

$$
x(t) = x_I(t) + jx_Q(t)
$$

where $x_I(t)$ and $x_Q(t)$ are the I and Q components, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

[image: hello]
<sub>(source: [radio-electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/pm-phase-modulation/GMSK-modulator-02.gif))</sub>

The two signals just before the summation forms the quadrature(Q) and inphase(I) components. Hence it should be added.

Comment: Perhaps some explanation of why I and Q are added, instead of a bald (and incorrect) statement, would be more helpful to the OP. Read, for example, the thoughtful answers provided by MBaz and JasonR before your one-liner.

Comment: sorry for the previous answer.I though of the above diagram and wrote it.